# Ruby regex to match string between variable and two digits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I'm not getting what I want from my regex.

I'm looking thru `@my_string` which contains:

```
"Black Multi/Wide Calf":[{"large":"http://ecx.images-willy.com/images
/I/41suNF66r4L.jpg","variant":"MAIN","hiRes":"http://ecx.images-willy.com
/images/I/51knTtAU6mL._UL1000_.jpg","thumb":"http://ecx.images-willy.com
/images/I/41suNF66r4L._US40_.jpg","main":{"http://ecx.images-willy.com/images
/I/51knTtAU6mL._UY500_.jpg":["500","500""]}}],"Dark Brown":
[{"large":"http://ecx.images......
```

And I have a variable which is:

```
@color = "Black Multi"
```

And my regex looks like:

```
/^#{@color}(.*)\d+(}\])$/i.match(@my_string)
```

I want the string that starts with "Black Multi" and ends with `}]`:

```
Black Multi/Wide Calf":[{"large":"http://ecx.images-willy.com/images
/I/41suNF66r4L.jpg","variant":"MAIN","hiRes":"http://ecx.images-willy.com
/images/I/51knTtAU6mL._UL1000_.jpg","thumb":"http://ecx.images-willy.com
/images/I/41suNF66r4L._US40_.jpg","main":{"http://ecx.images-willy.com/images
/I/51knTtAU6mL._UY500_.jpg":["500","500""]}}]
```

I'm getting nil with what I have. where did I jack this up?

Comment: it's not clear what @my_string is supposed to be equal to there.  It looks more like the contents of a hash which has been cut off towards the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your string is a JSON-encoded object. Don't try to parse it using regex. Instead parse it using a JSON parser, then access its contents like normal.

```
require 'json'

my_string = '{"Black Multi/Wide Calf":[{"large":"http://ecx.images-willy.com/images/I/41suNF66r4L.jpg","variant":"MAIN","hiRes":"http://ecx.images-willy.com/images/I/51knTtAU6mL._UL1000_.jpg","thumb":"http://ecx.images-willy.com/images/I/41suNF66r4L._US40_.jpg","main":{"http://ecx.images-willy.com/images/I/51knTtAU6mL._UY500_.jpg":["500","500"]}}]}'
obj = JSON[my_string]
# => {"Black Multi/Wide Calf"=>
#      [{"large"=>"http://ecx.images-willy.com/images/I/41suNF66r4L.jpg",
#        "variant"=>"MAIN",
#        "hiRes"=>
#         "http://ecx.images-willy.com/images/I/51knTtAU6mL._UL1000_.jpg",
#        "thumb"=>
#         "http://ecx.images-willy.com/images/I/41suNF66r4L._US40_.jpg",
#        "main"=>
#         {"http://ecx.images-willy.com/images/I/51knTtAU6mL._UY500_.jpg"=>
#           ["500", "500"]}}]}
```

Because it's now a regular object, in this case a hash, it's easy to access its key/value pairs:

```
obj["Black Multi/Wide Calf"] # => [{"large"=>"http://ecx.images-willy.com/images/I/41suNF66r4L.jpg", "variant"=>"MAIN", "hiRes"=>"http://ecx.images-willy.com/images/I/51knTtAU6mL._UL1000_.jpg", "thumb"=>"http://ecx.images-willy.com/images/I/41suNF66r4L._US40_.jpg", "main"=>{"http://ecx.images-willy.com/images/I/51knTtAU6mL._UY500_.jpg"=>["500", "500"]}}]
```

And it's easy to drill down:

```
obj["Black Multi/Wide Calf"][0]['large'] # => "http://ecx.images-willy.com/images/I/41suNF66r4L.jpg"
```

Comment: Awesome.. thanks for going above and beyond! But its the source from a webpage.. So I'm assuming it can't be json.. but heck I will try!

Comment: It *is* the source for a [JSON](http://json.org) representation of a JavaScript object. Don't use regex for this, instead use the right tools. Regular expressions will break badly if that string is dynamically built, which is very likely.

Comment: Also, if this is in a web page, how are you retrieving the JSON string itself? If you're using regex to get to that point you're doing it the hard and unrecommended way. You should use a HTML parser, such as Nokogiri.

Comment: Nice! Ok, that is great.. I'm using Mechanize and Nokogiri.. but I had no idea what it was and was just using regex and string match to get to where I was going..

Comment: Well, it's possible to do it via Regular expressions but at the same time it's very fragile and error-prone which is why we don't use them for parsing HTML or XML *except* when it's an extremely simple pattern and we aren't using matches for tag starts/end or quotes and there's no chance of the line being broken across a line boundary and case won't change and.... See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags. The answers discuss the possible problems well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the "multiline" flag (`/m`) to the regex:

```
str[/Black Multi.*?\}\]/m]
  #=> "Black Multi/Wide Calf\"......\"500\"\"]}}]"
```